# Time stamp before or after

Tags: swift, date, cocoa, cocoa-touch

I have a timestamp in a database. I need to determine whether the stamp is before or after today's date at 7 AM.

How do I do that?

Comment: What's your DB? Is it stored with timezone? If not, what timezone should I assume it to be in?

Comment: Hi, it would be GMT

Comment: Is it 7am in the user's timezone or in GMT?

Comment: And if it's _exactly_ 7am? Should it be considered before or after or a third case?

Comment: Hi, in the users time zone, and yes exactly 7am

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to be careful when comparing dates as timezone can cause a big headache. `NSDate` always stores time in UTC timezone. Depending on daylight saving times, local British time can be UTC+0 or UTC+1.

Give this a try:

```
// This extension is optional. It makes comparing dates easier
extension NSDate: Comparable {}
public func <(lhs: NSDate, rhs: NSDate) -> Bool {
    return lhs.timeIntervalSince1970 < rhs.timeIntervalSince1970
}

// This part simulates the time you get from the database
let dbCalendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
dbCalendar.timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: "GMT")!
let timestampFromDB = dbCalendar.dateWithEra(1, year: 2016, month: 5, day: 30, hour: 10, minute: 0, second: 0, nanosecond: 0)!

// Convert 7AM today from user's time to UTC
let userCalendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
let todayAt7 = userCalendar.dateBySettingHour(7, minute:0, second:0, ofDate: NSDate(), options: [])!

print(timestampFromDB < todayAt7)
```

Comment: Spot on! Thank you so much!

Comment: GMT never changes, it is never UTC+1. You probably mean that UK time changes, part of the year it is GMT, and during the summer it is BST (which is UTC+1). As you say, you need to be careful with time zones ;-)

Comment: @CRD A taste of my own medicine. Dang those daylight saving time!